# Error message not considering array

Tags: php

I want an error message to appear if the 'Name' field is left empty but instead it displays error messages for all the fields in the form.

```
$key = array('Name');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        while (is_array($val))
            $val = reset($val);
        if (is_string($val))
            $val = trim($val);
        if (empty($val)) {
            $err[] = "ERROR - $key is required";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be consistent when using brackets on single line if/while statements.

Comment: You're overwriting the `$key` variable in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Rocket shall I get rid of that line then?

Comment: @user1257518: You should change the variable name.

Comment: @Rocket simply change $key to another name?

Comment: @user1257518: Depends on what you're trying to do, currently the `$key = array('Name');` is useless, as `foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {` will immediately overwrite it.

Comment: I want the required field error to work only for 'name' field but at the moment its displaying the error message for every field in my form

Answer (score 0):

I would've done

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if($val == "Name")
        {

           if (empty($val)) {
               $err[] = "ERROR - $key is required";
               break;
           }
        }

    }
```

Just a note, this is untested

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this just redirects to my main page, which should only happen if the 'Name' has been entered